# How can i call FragmentManager from Fragment? Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm building alarm app and trying to open time picker dialog. I need to get time data after it closed. The problem is in `.show()` function. It doesn't work in fragment. It says `None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.`

My class

```
class AlarmPickerDialog : DialogFragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container:
    ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View {

        var myView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.alarm_time_picker, container, false)

        return myView
    }
}
```

And my calling method

```
val alarmDialog = AlarmPickerDialog()
val fm = getActivity()!!.getSupportFragmentManager()
alarmDialog.show(fm, "MyDialog")
```

Maybe there is a better method to get time data?

Comment: Show doesn't take any arguments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem:** It seems `AlarmPickerDialog` extends from `android.app.DialogFragment` instead of `android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment`.

**Solution:** Change your code to

```
// Comment-out this line
// import android.app.DialogFragment

// Add this line
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment

class AlarmPickerDialog : DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        var myView = inflater!!.inflate(R.layout.alarm_time_picker, container, false)
        return myView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey try to follow these steps, 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment your question says how to call fragment manager, but you already calling it,
That's why your question is not so clearing the problem and try to follow this docs may it helps.

Comment: hello, my code doesn't compiles with this `.show()` calling, so i didn't call FragmentManager yet.

Answer (score -1):

Here is an solution to your code:

**Code for DialogFragment**

```
class ListFragment: DialogFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, container)
        var pioneers = arrayOf("Jon Snow", "Mother of Dragon-Khalessi", "Ned Stark", "Benjen Stark", "Cathlyen Stark", "Arya Stark", "Sansa Stark", "Littelfiger", "Jamie Lannister")

        val myListView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.myListView) as ListView
        myListView!!.adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, pioneers)

        this.dialog.setTitle("Game Of Thrones")

        myListView.setOnItemClickListener {
            adapterView,
            view,
            position,
            l
            -> Toast.makeText(activity, pioneers[position], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        return rootView
    }
}


In your activity you can make call something like this

val openFragmentBtn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.openFragmentID)

//On button Click Open Dialog Fragment
    val openFragmentBtn = findViewById(R.id.openFragmentID) as Button

            val fm = supportFragmentManager
            val listFragment= ListFragment()

            openFragmentBtn.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
                override fun onClick(view: View) {
                    listFragment.show(fm, "PioneersFragment_tag")
                }
            })
```

Try this

```
val pop = alarm_first()
val fm = this@YourActivityName.fragmentManager
pop.show(fm, "name")
```

I had implemented this code for learning purpose but if it work for you I am happy to help

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Unfortunately i tried this, but it doesn't work in fragment.

Comment: There is no supportFragmentManager in a kotlin fragment